# auto fill height of a table in Itext 8

Tags: java, itext

I want to auto fill the remaining height of a table by using Itext8. I'm using the following code.

```
package TabellaProva;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue;

public class NestedTable {
    private static final String DEST = "./prova.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
        Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);

        float[] colWidths = { 1, 1 };
        Table externalTable = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(colWidths));

        Table leftNestedTable = new Table(2);
        leftNestedTable.setAutoLayout();
        Table rightNestedTable = new Table(2);
        rightNestedTable.setAutoLayout();

        Paragraph lp = new Paragraph("ciaone");
        Cell lc = new Cell().add(lp);
        Cell lc2 = new Cell().add(lp);

        leftNestedTable.addCell(lc);
        leftNestedTable.addCell(lc2);

        Paragraph rp = new Paragraph("sono a destra sono a destrasono a destrasono a destrasono a destrasono a destra");
        rightNestedTable.addCell(rp);
        rightNestedTable.addCell(rp);
        externalTable.addCell(leftNestedTable);
        externalTable.addCell(rightNestedTable);

        document.add(externalTable);
        document.close();

        System.out.println("DOcument generated");
    }
}
```

[this is the table that i obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRtfH.png)

i would like to obtain a cell in the left that occupies all the available height